# Is it possible to 'import as' with only a few exports?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I want to import a handful of an mode module's exports under a namespace. I want to do this because if I import the entire module, it adds a ton of bulk to my project.

Is something like this possible?

```
import { FaUser, FaUsers, FaScroll } as FaIcons from 'react-icons/fa';
```

Then I would be able to do something like this in my code.

```
const a = 'FaUser';
const myIcon = FaIcons[a];
```

Answer (score 1):

It is possible to perform selected imports.

```
import { FaUser, FaUsers, FaScroll } as FaIcons from 'react-icons/fa';
```

You can access FaUser, FaUsers, and FaScroll as -

1. FaIcons.FaUser
2. FaIcons.FaUsers
3. FaIcons.FaScroll